# Android Notification doesn't trigger BroadcastReceiver to launch background action

Tags: android, notifications

I am having trouble with being able to execute an action on clicking a button in an Android Notification. I need this action to be in the background and should not open an activity. I am ultimately trying to record the data usage but for now just need to get the BroadcastReceiver to work.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, BlankActivity.class);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                (int) System.currentTimeMillis(),
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, StartRecording.class);
        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, mIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("Monitor Resources")
                        .setContentText("Choose your action")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.opened_email_envelope)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.opened_email_envelope, "Start", mPendingIntent)
                        .setContentIntent(mPendingIntent)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.opened_email_envelope, "Stop", resultPendingIntent);

        int mId = 001;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());

}

class StartRecording extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MonitorSpeed", "BroadcastReceiver Started");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I have also registered the service in the manifest file in this way:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BlankActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_blank"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
<receiver android:name=".helper.NotificationReceiver" />
<receiver
    android:name=".StartRecording">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.sd.monitorspeed.BROADCAST" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

What am I doing wrong? Could anyone help me point out the mistake?

Comment: Your `<receiver>`s need to go in between the `<application>` tags, just like the `<activity>`s.

Comment: It worked! Thank you soo much!
It is though only able to run if I declare my BroadcastReceiver class in a new file i.e. declare it public. Otherwise it gives the error that the class isn't accessible from the ActivityThread. Any ideas there?

Comment: Yeah, after I commented, I started to wonder where the `StartRecording` class was. If you statically register a Receiver class in the manifest like that, and it's a nested class - i.e., it's inside another class - it must be `public static`, and the `name` attribute would be a little different. In this case, it'd be `android:name=".MainActivity$StartRecording"`. Since it's `static`, though, you can't directly access any instance members of `MainActivity`, so you don't really gain anything from keeping it in the same file, other than maybe organization.

Comment: Ah! Okay. I think it would be better that I put it in another file, specially since I need to do a lot more than just display a Toast. Thank you for your help!